# Ubuntu 20.04 failed to fetch dependencies

Tags: apt, systemd-timesyncd

I'm trying to install systemd-timesyncd with `apt install systemd-timesyncd` and retrive 404 error.

```
➜  ~ apt install systemd-timesyncd

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libopts25 sntp
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  systemd-timesyncd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 243 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 systemd-timesyncd amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Anyone can help me?

**EDIT**

```
 / apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 370d 10h 17min 57s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 998d 2h 18min 54s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 998d 2h 18min 20s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

➜  / date
Fri Apr 19 09:15:17 CEST 2019

➜  / timedatectl status
               Local time: Fri 2019-04-19 09:15:27 CEST
           Universal time: Fri 2019-04-19 07:15:27 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: Europe/Madrid (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no

➜  / sudo hwclock --hctosys --verbose
hwclock from util-linux 2.34
System Time: 1555659408.378273
Trying to open: /dev/rtc0
Trying to open: /dev/rtc
Trying to open: /dev/misc/rtc
No usable clock interface found.
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
```

Comment: Update your software lists (ie. `sudo apt update`) and check for issues; the package you pasted is very *outdated* as what's available now is `systemd-timesyncd | 245.4-4ubuntu3.14 | focal-updates    | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`  Once your software lists are *up to date* your system will look & find the correct package.

Comment: @guiverc When `apt update` i have this error `E: Release file for http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 370d 10h 26min 19s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.` I think the problem is my datetime `date -> Fri Apr 19 09:07:46 CEST 2019` That is the reason that i need to install systemd-timesyncd

Comment: Check your system clock & timezone; though 370 days out means it's more than timezone but invalid clock.  Correct your systems date & time.

Comment: Run: `sudo hwclock --hctosys`

Comment: @guiverc that is what i'm trying, correct the date and time. More info in question on edit part.
@Someone when run `sudo hwclock --hctosys` i have this message `hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.` I put verbose mode info in question on edit part.

Comment: Hmm... Run: `cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource` and provide the output.

Comment: @Someone I run `cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
tsc hpet acpi_pm` 
I don't know if it's important but my server is a virtual ubuntu server on a LXC container of proxmox.

Comment: Found the issue.

Comment: @Someone and what is the issue? is not correct clocksource?......if you can help me I'd be very gratefull

Comment: @xabikip Posted an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133087/discussion-between-someone-and-xabikip).

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an issue with your system time. The repository wasn't valid at the time your system is frozen on. Take a look at this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/852008) on Server fault:

> The problem seems to be connected to `clocksource`, check
> `available_clocksource`:
>
> ```
> $ cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
> tsc hpet acpi_pm
> ```
>
> Based on [answer to "What does “clocksource tsc unstable” mean?"](https://superuser.com/questions/393969/what-does-clocksource-tsc-unstable-mean)
> it looks like [TSC (Time Stamp Counter)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) is not very reliable.
>
> By updating `/etc/default/grub` you can switch to another available
> clocksource. I'm using [HPET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer).
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="clocksource=hpet"
> ```
>
> and updating grub:
>
> ```
> update-grub2
> ```
>
> After reboot `hwclock` works again (just reboot without any
> modification might have helped as well - it might be just question for
> how long).
>
> **NOTE**: Optimal clocksource might depend on your motherboard and CPU model.

So, follow these steps to correct your time:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` as root using a text editor (eg:- `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`)
2. Locate the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`.
3. Change the line to look like:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="clocksource=hpet"
   ```
4. Update grub:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Reboot to confirm:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```
6. Now update again:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
7. Install the package:

   ```
   sudo apt install systemd-timesyncd
   ```

Comment: I have not grub file in `/etc/default` -> `/etc/default ls
apache-htcacheclean  bsdmainutils  console-setup  cron  dbus  irqbalance  keyboard  locale  mysql  networkd-dispatcher  nss  ntp  rcS  rsync  ssh  ufw  useradd`

Comment: My server is a virtual ubuntu server on a LXC container of proxmox